# laravel4.2 queue send email issue

Tags: email, laravel, redis, queue

I use laravel 4.2 redis. queue send email , but right now it has some problem.  first  when I change template of email  it keep send out old template to email address, second sometimes  it keep send out several duplicated email to same address. I have no any clue how to start to investigate those issue any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since daemon queue workers are long-lived processes, they will not pick up changes in your code without being restarted. the simpliest way is to run

```
 php artisan queue:restart
```

to restart your workers. with the duplicated email i guess your jobs are not been deleted from the queue when its fired.

Comment: But 1) laravel4.2 dont have this command , I restart supervisor and redis both but it still doesn't work

Comment: 2) it not always the case sometime it works fine  bye way I just enable the queue to redis and change Email send to Email:queue  how to delete job after send email

Comment: My bad the laravel4.1 dont have queue:restart command but laravel4.2 have, my problem does not caused by queue:listen  is caused by that I use supervisor , everytime I restart a supervisor  will generate a new process which running queuen:listen, So that means I have to kill the process otherwise system will lock old template. solution would be kill process and restart supervisor, restart queue thanks @oseintow

Comment: Just remember to run php artisan queue:restart any time you deploy your code it won't kill already started process. Can you accept my answer or vote